# atomically only incrementing id

Tags: c#, mongodb

The function below has the purpose of creating IdentityStore objects that store a sequence of numbers and a usedId. Once we reach the maximu size of rows it will drop the collection and recreate it starting from 0. I need this operation to work atomically since the sequence of numbers have to be unique. Currently its not working aromatically. What approach can I take to lock this function per call.

There can be more than one server and there will be more than one instance running. This would only lock on the single instance And race conditions exist between multiple servers. How can i lock this on multiple instances/machines.

> EDIT:

I understand now that I will need to use Mutex in order for threads to be able to use this code block across multiple instances of the application. If the Mutex does not exist use the existing one. Is this implementation below correct? I used a multi thread unit test and it is currently passing. But I am unsure if the code block will be executed properly within the mutex. I based this implementation after reading the MSDM file on this subject

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=vs.90).aspx

```
private int _sequence = 0;
private long _lastgen = -1;
private MongoDBRepository<IdentityStore> _mongoDBRepository;


public MongoIdGenerator(string mongoConnectionString)
{
_mongoDBRepository = new MongoDBRepository<IdentityStore>(mongoConnectionString);
}

public string GetIdForKey(string key, int maxSize)
{
var requestInitialOwnership = true;
bool mutexWasCreated;
Mutex m = new Mutex(
        requestInitialOwnership,
        "MyMutex", 
        out mutexWasCreated);

// This thread owns the mutex only if it both requested  
// initial ownership and created the named mutex. Otherwise, 
// it can request the named mutex by calling WaitOne. 
if (!(requestInitialOwnership && mutexWasCreated))
{
    m.WaitOne();
}

// Once the process has gained control of the named mutex, 
// Hold onto it until the mongo record has been successfully created.
var collection = _mongoDBRepository.Collection;
IdentityStore idStore = new IdentityStore();
idStore.key = string.Empty;

if (_lastgen != -1)
{
    idStore = collection.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(i => i.usedId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (_sequence < maxSize && idStore != null)
    {
        var arrayOfDigits = _sequence.ToString().Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString()));
        var _sequenceOfNumbers = _sequence.ToString().PadLeft((10 - arrayOfDigits.Count()), '0');

        idStore.key = _sequenceOfNumbers;
        idStore.usedId = _sequence;

        _sequence++;
    }
    else
    {
        collection.Database.DropCollection(collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName);

        _sequence = 0;
        _lastgen = 0;

        idStore.key = "000000000";
        idStore.usedId = _sequence;

        _sequence++;
    }
}
else
{
    _sequence = 0;
    _lastgen = 0;

    idStore.key = "000000000";
    idStore.usedId = _sequence;

    _sequence++;
}

unchecked
{
    collection.InsertOne(idStore);

    // Call ReleaseMutex to allow other threads to gain control 
    // of the named mutex. If you keep a reference to the local 
    // Mutex, you can call WaitOne to request control of the  
    // named mutex.
    m.ReleaseMutex();
    return idStore.key;

}
```

Comment: There will be one instance of the app running or multiple ones? And on the same machine or different ones if there are multiple instances?

Comment: @Gusman there will be only one instance of the app running but there can be multiple threads hitting this function.

Comment: Then the lock must be enough, is genLock static?

Comment: @Gusman 
        private object genlock = new object();

Comment: Make it static, if there are multiple instances of the class each one will use a different object to lock the function

Comment: @Gusman awesome will do. So instantiating a private static object should be enough to lock this guy? private static object genlock = new object();

Comment: Yes, it should if that's the real problem, as you were creating different lockers (one per instance) the lock mechanism didn't saw the object as being locked and the function continued to execute. But that's only the case if you have multiple instances of the class with the GetIdForKey function.

Comment: @Gusman apparently I was wrong, I was under the impression this was only going to run under one instance but there are multiple instances of this app

Comment: Then you can use a system-wide mutex (a named mutex) if they are running on the same machine. Else, you have a problem, mongo, as a no-sql db it does not provide transactions, so you need to find a way to mantain this as unique. May be you can create a second service which gets in charge to create those unique counts and run only of those services, so the other apps call the service to generate the ids.